# Div does not adjust to fit height and width of the image

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, html, jquery-cycle

I have a div (div#slideImage) and within a few images.

But this is not div by adjusting the images inside that div.

[See](http://www.amsdarquitetura.com.br/Project/Details?ProjectID=100) the full page.
Note that the size of the div (width: 75px; height: 28px;) is smaller than the size of the image.

I'm using the plugin [jquery.cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't what you were expecting, but can't you just resize the image? It seems to make more sense to me than expecting the div to do the work for you.

Comment: I can not set a size for the photos vary in size and the text should fit. The pictures can have a maximum width of 460px (1px by 460px).

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Are you saying that you don't have prior control over the photos? What i meant was that you could just edit them in photoshop or something.

Comment: the client registers the photos, then they can come in varying sizes.

I set the pthon size on upload, not to pass the size I informed you.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, what you really want to do is have the picture be it's normal size, unless it is over 460px in which case it reduces to 460px while keeping the same aspect ratio?

Comment: yes, but that he was already doing. The problem was keeping the pictures and text side by side.

But I've got ... see the site. I fixed the div where the images are. It was not what I wanted .. but had no choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the dimensions of a div, then contained nodes will either be clipped or scrolled depending on the div's overflow property. Your best bet is to set the dimensions of the div to more useful values.

Comment: I can not set a size for the photos vary in size and the text should fit. The pictures can have a maximum width of 460px (1px by 460px).